# SORTING THE string ROW having numeric values

Tags: sql-server

I have a column with data like this:

```
COMPRESSIN 1(PB4),
COMPRESSIN 12(PB4),
COMPRESSIN 3(PB4).
```

I want to order the column by the COMPRESSION. So 1, 3, and 12 respectively as shown below:

```
COMPRESSION 1(PB4),
COMPRESSION 3(PB4),
COMPRESSION 12(PB4).
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please STOP SHOUTING. Typing in ALL CAPS makes your question difficult to read and understand, and it's really rude and annoying. You should take the [tour] and read through the [help] pages, especially [ask], before posting your next question here.

Comment: Is your data consistent? by that I mean do you always have COMPRESSION at the beginning and the number you want to use as a sort always has (xxx) after it? As you are discovering it is not easy to isolate one piece of data when it is crammed together with other data. The data you have here violates 1NF because you have multiple pieces of information in a single tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You need to order by a substring.

```
...
order by 
   substring(yourColumn,12,99)
```

This basically sorts on everything after `'COMPRESSION '` It's important to know that this is still sorting based on `varchar` order, which is using unicode decimal values. Thus, b comes before A due to it's case sensitivity, etc...

If your columns all end with the (XXX) pattern, you can use this to circumvent this.

```
order by 
   left(substring(yourColumn,12,99),len(substring(yourColumn,12,99)) - 5)
```

Comment: COMPRESSIN 1(PB4),
COMPRESSIN 12(PB4)  but it sort like this only it will compare both strings

Comment: What is your comment supposed to mean?

Comment: i didn't get the sorted order as i am given above   i want after compression int values only in sorted order

Comment: @ajay you didn't read what i wrote about varchar sorting. I added an edit that will work for the test data

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do this is to remove the non-numeric portion while ordering:

```
ORDER BY CAST(
          REPLACE(
           REPLACE(YourColumn, 'COMPRESSION ','')
          , '(PB4)','')
         AS int) ASC
```

Comment: This works unless compression and/or (PB4) ever change. If they don't ever change, what's the point of them being stored in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a potential solution or at least one that can help put you in the right direction. I recommend you consider the clarity of your question and add more detail.

```
SELECT
    ColumnName
FROM
    TableName
ORDER BY
    CAST(SUBSTRING(ColumnName, CHARINDEX(' ', ColumnName) + 1, CHARINDEX('(', ColumnName) - CHARINDEX(' ', ColumnName) - 1) AS int)
```

This works by using CHARINDEX to find the space after compression as a starting position (+1 to begin after the space) and the open parenthesis as the ending position to isolate the numeric value for sorting. You also need to convert this value to some type of numeric value like an integer.

Comment: Oh, one other thought, if I am at all interpreting this correctly. You should consider breaking up this string into multiple fields. If you need to sort on one part of it as a numeric value, then it seems like that needs to be in a column by itself. Looking at the samples you gave, maybe 3 columns is a better design for this one field.